# Java - How to hold two keys at same time?

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, key, removechild

I'm using a recyclerView to show two images at time. Once the user clicks in one of them, both should be removed from Firebase database.The fact is... When the activity starts I can get both image keys.

But once the user clicks I can only remove the image that was clicked, as expected. How do I hold both image keys to remove after the click?

```
protected void populateViewHolder(final ImagesHolder viewHolder, final Images model, int position) {


        final  String image_key = getRef(position).getKey();
        Toast.makeText(TesteActivity.this, foto_key, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); // Here I can get both keys!

viewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

              mDatabaseTeste = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("imagesForUsers").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child(image_key);//
              mDatabaseTeste.removeValue();

    }
}
```

Comment: this is really a firebase issue, or?

Answer (score 0):

You can map keys.
You said that in you activity you have both keys.

So create a Map like this

```
Map<String, String> keysMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

Then for each couple of keys (key1, key2 in this case) you put them into the map.

```
keysMap.put(key1, key2);
keysMap.put(key2, key1);
```

Then in your `populateViewHolder(...)` method, change the onClick listener code to this:

```
mDatabaseTeste = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("imagesForUsers").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child(image_key);//
mDatabaseTeste.removeValue();

if(keysMap.containsKey(image_key)) {
    //Gets the key associated to the image_key
    String relatedKey = keysMap.get(image_key);
    mDatabaseTeste = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("imagesForUsers").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child(relatedKey);//
    mDatabaseTeste.removeValue();
}
```

Comment: I have both keys but in the same string. When I use the toast command, it shows one and then the other image key. I tried to separate into different strings but I couldn't. So I think I can't use map for this. Am I right?

Comment: For example you have a string like this "key1:key2" ? If it's the case you can separate the two keys by using the split method. String[] keys = new String("key1:key2").split(":"); Can you post the string that contains the keys? so we can see what can be done

Comment: I couldn't recognize the type of string that it's generating when I use this "String image_key = getRef(position).getKey();". I tried to split using but it didn't work. 
"String[] parts = image_key.split(":");
 String part1 = parts[0]; 
 String part2 = parts[1];" It says that index 1 doesn't exist and when I toast the index 0 both keys appear.

Comment: I solve it. It was just really stupid mistake. I lost hours and I want to kill myself because of it (I'm beginner). I just have to use "-", instead of "," or anything else. Anyway... Thank you so much!